# How to create Material Button Dynamically?

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to create material button dynamically. I have added all the dependency and everything. If I create it in XML file it works perfectly but when I try to create it dynamically it gives the error

Creating Material Button that I tried:

````
MaterialButton materialButton = new MaterialButton(context);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    myLayout.addView(materialButton, layoutParams);```
````

My style xml looks like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" 
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

It gives run time Error 
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant)."

Answer found:
passing getActivity() as context solved my issue

Comment: Its telling you exactly what the problem is.  You need to put a theme on your Activity that's either Theme.MaterialComponents, or a child of that theme.

Comment: the error says" the app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant)" which I have in the styles

Comment: @AshimGhimire see my edited answer..its working in my app..it will be helpul

Answer (score -1):

Just pass style in Material Button's constructor..

```
    MaterialButton materialButton = new MaterialButton(this, null, R.attr.borderlessButtonStyle);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearHome.addView(materialButton, layoutParams);
    String buttonText = "Button Name";
    materialButton.setText(buttonText);
    materialButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Dit it already. But I don't see any difference. But Thanks for the help.